# ArrayList logic error, data is inserted to array if all data is match if condition

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my data stored in arraylist only if all of the data match "if condition".
suppose any data that match should be stored in arraylist.

```
    searchDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    geofenceDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Geo-fence");

    searchList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    searchList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    geofenceDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            final double userLat = snapshot.child(userID).child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            final double userLng = snapshot.child(userID).child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            final double userRadius = snapshot.child(userID).child("Radius").getValue(Double.class);

            for (DataSnapshot tutorSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                String fetchID = tutorSnapshot.getKey();
                double tutorLat = tutorSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double tutorLng = tutorSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                //Get all Tutor data from Database
                    searchDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            tutorArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            //tutorArrayList.clear();
                            for (DataSnapshot key : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                User tutor = key.getValue(User.class);
                                String typeData = tutor.getType().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                                if (calculateDistanceInKilometer(userLat,userLng,tutorLat,tutorLng) <= userRadius){
                                    if (typeData.equals("tutor")){
                                        tutorArrayList.add(tutor);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "fetchID: "+fetchID ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Radius: "+userRadius ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Distance: "+calculateDistanceInKilometer(userLat,userLng,tutorLat,tutorLng) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            adapter = new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), tutorArrayList);
                            searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            if (adapter.getItemCount()==0){
                                searchList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }else {
                                searchList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Example Output of calculation:

> Radius set to = 10 and 300

dataset

> 1- 0.0
> 2- 6.0
> 3- 290.0

Result

> if Radius is 10 no data stored in Array
> if Radius is 300 all data stored in array

Expected output to be:

> If Radius set to 10, data1 and data2 stored
> if Radius set to 300, all data stored

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: I’m on the same page as you. That is why i put the title as logic error. Because there is no possible error in coding

Comment: @AlexMamo the code does not showing output as it should. it should only when all the data less than radius. but now showing if the some of data is less than radius